# Why is my world anchor resetting?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

We just started up a new tekkit server after the last one got corrupted in a power outage and the backup was too old.

But it's exhibiting some odd behavior, particularly in regards to world anchors. They are working fine ... most of the time. But if the server shuts down, they stop working until we actually go to the location of the anchor and then it starts working again.

It's not a big deal usually, but it seems to be causing some issues with my quarries where I'm getting big piles of cobblestone and dirt, which grows the longer I take to get to the area and "refresh" it and get them going into the pipes again.

Does anybody know what's causing this behavior, and more importantly, a fix?

Comment: As an aside, it also looks like the server lost the recipes my transmutation table had ... Maybe related?

Comment: can we know the versions of minecraft and tekkit, the newest forge (from 1.4.2 onward) has updated chunk loading mechanics which now only need the age loaded for all chunk-loaded chunks to load

Comment: the server is running tekkit 3.1.2/ minecraft 1.2.5

Comment: It's probably because when you shut the server down, it unloads all chunks. When you start it up again, it only reloads the chunks near the player. World anchors can keep a chunk loaded, but I don't think they can make a chunk load if it isn't already.

Comment: That makes sense... I guess just not taking the server down would be a good step :p

Comment: Guess I'll make that an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you shut down the server, Minecraft unloads all chunks. When you start it again, it begins with no chunks loaded, and loads chunks as players log in. Because it hasn't 'looked' at the chunks with the world anchors in them, Minecraft doesn't know that they need to stay loaded. So long as a chunk is loaded, a world anchor can keep it loaded, but they cannot cause a chunk to load if it isn't already loaded.

Comment: However, tekkit is suppost to load world anchors on startup

Comment: @legacy - It is? Where did you find that?

Comment: Use of the tekkit server. World anchors would always load at startup (tekkit server running on OSX with neather ores removed)